# Increment if condition is met for more than 48 hours

Tags: r

I have the following data on the occurrence of a certain symptom in a patient ('symptom'). I have to count the number of episodes this symptom occurs ('symptom_episode') and if the symptom is not present for >48hours, I need to increment 'recovery' +1.
Here is an example with the desired output for 'symptom_episode' and for 'recovery':

```
  dat=data.table(
  date=c("2015-01-01 06:00:00 UTC","2015-01-01 16:53:00 UTC","2015-01-02 05:15:00 UTC","2015-01-03 05:28:00 UTC","2015-01-04 05:13:00 UTC","2015-01-05 05:25:00 UTC","2015-01-06 05:11:00 UTC","2015-01-07 05:25:00 UTC","2015-01-08 05:20:00 UTC","2015-01-09 05:17:00 UTC","2015-01-09 15:25:00 UTC","2015-01-10 05:22:00 UTC","2015-01-11 05:19:00 UTC"),
  symptom=c(0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
  symptom_episode=c(0,1,1,1,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0),
  recovery=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
)
```

My problem is, that I have no idea on how to either count the number of symptom-episodes nor on how to conduct the recovery part.
I believe that the recovery part should be possible with some kind of rollapply-solution!?

I would really appreciate any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` approach, not the most concise but hopefully makes sense.

```
library(dplyr); library(lubridate)
output <- dat %>%
  mutate(date = ymd_hms(date)) %>%
  mutate(symptom_ep_calc = if_else(symptom > 0, cumsum(symptom > 0 & lag(symptom) == 0), 0L),
         region = cumsum(symptom_ep_calc != lag(symptom_ep_calc, default = 0)))

output %>%
  group_by(region, symptom_ep_calc) %>% summarize(end = max(date)) %>% ungroup() %>%
  mutate(time_recovered = (end - lag(end, default = min(output$date))) / dhours(1),
         recovery_calc = cumsum(time_recovered > 48 & symptom_ep_calc == 0)) %>%
  right_join(output) %>%
  select(date, symptom, symptom_ep_calc, recovery_calc)


# A tibble: 13 x 4
   date                symptom symptom_ep_calc recovery_calc
   <dttm>                <dbl>           <int>         <int>
 1 2015-01-01 06:00:00       0               0             0
 2 2015-01-01 16:53:00       1               1             0
 3 2015-01-02 05:15:00       1               1             0
 4 2015-01-03 05:28:00       1               1             0
 5 2015-01-04 05:13:00       0               0             0
 6 2015-01-05 05:25:00       0               0             0
 7 2015-01-06 05:11:00       1               2             0
 8 2015-01-07 05:25:00       1               2             0
 9 2015-01-08 05:20:00       0               0             1
10 2015-01-09 05:17:00       0               0             1
11 2015-01-09 15:25:00       0               0             1
12 2015-01-10 05:22:00       0               0             1
13 2015-01-11 05:19:00       0               0             1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I changed the last value to test the result (should be 1 as symptom_episode = 0 and time is <48hrs.

```
> library(data.table)
> library(dplyr)
> dat=data.table(
+   date=c("2015-01-01 06:00:00 UTC","2015-01-01 16:53:00 UTC","2015-01-02 05:15:00 UTC","2015-01-03 05:28:00 UTC","2015-01-04 05:13:00 UTC","2015-01-05 05:25:00 UTC","2015-01-06 05:11:00 UTC","2015-01-07 05:25:00 UTC","2015-01-08 05:20:00 UTC","2015-01-09 05:17:00 UTC","2015-01-09 15:25:00 UTC","2015-01-10 05:22:00 UTC","2015-01-15 05:19:00 UTC"),
+   symptom=c(0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0),
+   symptom_episode=c(0,1,1,1,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0),
+   recovery=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
+ )
> 
> 
> dat$hours <- c(NA, difftime(dat$date[-1],
+                            dat$date[-nrow(dat)],
+                            units="hours"))
> 
> dat$recovery[dat$hours<48] <- 0
> 
> dat$recovery[dat$hours>48 & dat$symptom_episode==0]<-1
> 
> head(dat)
                      date symptom symptom_episode recovery    hours
1: 2015-01-01 06:00:00 UTC       0               0        0       NA
2: 2015-01-01 16:53:00 UTC       1               1        0 10.88333
3: 2015-01-02 05:15:00 UTC       1               1        0 12.36667
4: 2015-01-03 05:28:00 UTC       1               1        0 24.21667
5: 2015-01-04 05:13:00 UTC       0               0        0 23.75000
6: 2015-01-05 05:25:00 UTC       0               0        0 24.20000
...
head(dat[13,]
#correctly updates 'recovery' value to 1.

date symptom symptom_episode recovery  hours
1: 2015-01-15 05:19:00 UTC       0               0        1 119.95
```